# Exhaustive Search in sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, time-complexity

What would be the procedure on how to find a sorted list of an array with exhaustive search in an algorithmic way? What would the time complexity be? I tried doing the following, but wouldn't you have to make a comparison in the algorithm to check to see if the solution is correct to your current permutation (i.e. list)?

For example, take a list with the following elements:

10 3 7

Our goal is to find the corresponding sorted array which is 3 7 10. In order to find this we will need to make n! permutations (distinct list of arrays) so we can find the correct sorting of our list above. In total we will have 6 different permutations (i.e. different list) of arrays using exhaustive search to sort our array. For example, look below to see the distinct list of permutations (distinct list of arrays):

1st possibility: 10 3 7
2nd possibility: 10 7 3
3rd possibility: 3 10 7
4th possibility: 3 7 10
5th possibility: 7 10 3
6th possibility: 7 3 10

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: @manetsus sorry about the confusing question. I have changed it to correspond to what it is exactly I am referring to.

Comment: Generating and testing every permutation is O(n!), which is very time-consuming. There are much faster ways to sort an array. I suggest you try sorting the list `{10, 3, 7, 9, 5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 6}` by hand, and notice the algorithm you are using-- I'm sure you do not test all 3628800 permutations in your head!

Comment: @Beta I understand that it's not feasible to do, but how are you suppose to check if one solution is correct over the other possibilities?

Comment: Are you asking how to test whether a given permutation is in sorted order? Iterate from the beginning of the array to the end, and if you find an element that is less than the previous one, the array fails the test.

Comment: @Beta will this comparison be done in O(n) time? What will be the time complexity of doing so?

Comment: One comparison (i.e. testing whether a given permutation is in sorted order) is O(n).